# textDirection not working after upgrading Flutter to 2.5.0

Tags: flutter, dart

the following was working fine in 2.2.3 Flutter :

```
child: Text(
       "text example",
       textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, // not working on Flutter 2.5.0
       style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ),  ),
```

now i upgraded to Flutter 2.5.0 and it shows the following error :

```
The getter 'ltr' isn't defined for the type 'TextDirection'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried? textAlign? on this

```
      Text(
          " left",
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
```

or do the direction text on column like this

```
  Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    children: [
     Text("SomeText")
    ]
  )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'll have to refractor a lot of code , what i'm looking for is the textDirection inside the Text widget was it removed from Flutter or something ?

Comment: have you tried text align if your text is wrap on Container.